# SCNSceneSource identifiers with usdz file are empty

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit, usdz

We are working on a project with ARKit 2 + SceneKit, iOS 12.
We were able to retrieve `CAAnimation` instances with `.dae` files and control them at runtime.
Now, we are trying `.usdz`, but none of the classes can be extracted from `SCNSceneSource` with usdz :

```
let source = SCNSceneSource(url: url, options: options)
let animationIdentifiers = source?.identifiersOfEntries(withClass: CAAnimation.self)
```

`animationIdentifiers` is always empty. The same goes for all classes listed in the documentation for this function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenesource/1523656-identifiersofentries

We have tested our own usdz creations as well as some usdz from https://fusionar.app.

Tough, the animations play nicely when viewing the file either on iOS or in Xcode, where we have access to the animations and scene graph settings :

[image: Xcode animation]

But definitely not from code at runtime, so we are unable to control the animations.

Have you ever had this issue ?

Any insight on this ?

Comment: complete how to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75093081/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving entries from a `SCNSceneSource` only works for Collada files. When working with USDZ file you'll have to traverse the node hierarchy and retrieve the animation from the node that holds it using [`-animationPlayerForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimatable/2866026-animationplayerforkey?language=objc).

Comment: nice, could you explain why ?